# UIBarButtonItem How to Disable Accessibility (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, accessibility, uibarbuttonitem

SO,

I am trying to disable the VoiceOver accessibility for a UIBarButtonItem which I have added to the leftBarButtonItems of a UINavigationController. While I can disable it for buttons without a title, I can't seem to disable it for buttons with a title. For example:

```
// Create the legend UIBarButtonItem
UIBarButtonItem *legendMenuBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Legend" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:tool action:@selector(activate)];

// Should disable accessibility on the button, still enabled for subviews
[legendMenuBarItem setIsAccessibilityElement:FALSE];

// Remove "button" from VoiceOver speech for the button 
[legendMenuBarItem setAccessibilityTraits:UIAccessibilityTraitNone];

// Removed "Legend" from being spoken, but the button is still tappable in accessibility mode 
[legendMenuBarItem setAccessibilityLabel:@" "]; 

// Attempt to remove any accessibility elements... no real effect
[legendMenuBarItem setAccessibilityElements:nil]; 

// Supposedly this should disable all subviews from being accessible? Doesn't work...
[legendMenuBarItem setAccessibilityElementsHidden:TRUE]; 


// Add legend UIBarButtonItem to the end of the leftBarButtonItems 
NSMutableArray *currentLeftBarItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.navigationItem leftBarButtonItems]];
[currentLeftBarItems addObject:legendMenuBarItem];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItems:currentLeftBarItems];
```

I have tried various methods to disable the VoiceOver but even in this current setup it still reads "Legend" when I tap on the button.

**More scenarios I have tried:**

This disables all speech (desired) but still allows the button to be interactive (not desired):

```
[legendMenuBarItem setAccessibilityLabel:@" "]; 
[legendMenuBarItem setIsAccessibilityElement:TRUE];
[legendMenuBarItem setAccessibilityTraits:UIAccessibilityTraitNone];
```

This, supposedly, should disable VoiceOver for the UIBarButtonItem and it's subviews (desired) but it doesn't (undesired):

```
[legendMenuBarItem setIsAccessibilityElement:TRUE];
[legendMenuBarItem setAccessibilityElementsHidden:TRUE];
```

In summary... my question is how in the world to disable accessible interactivity entirely? Normally I use `setIsAccessibilityElement:FALSE` and that works great. But no such luck this time.

Thanks!

Comment: i thought there will be accessibility option available for the bar button item so that i can disable it on storyboard,but it only shows for some elements.'

Comment: @TejaNandamuri, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

The `setAccessibilityElementsHidden` only works when that UIElement really have some elements in it.

Try to `setAccessibilityElementsHidden` to `YES` for the Toolbar or for the Container where your bar buttons exist.

**Edit:** If you dont want the accessibility for particular bar button , then you need to add that button to toolBar's accessibility elements which is a `NSArray` and then hide it as per your requirement.

**Edit:**      This disabled accessibility for the navigation item

```
  self.navigationController.navigationBar.accessibilityElementsHidden=YES;
```

Comment: I added the lines ````[self.navigationItem setAccessibilityElements:@[legendMenuBarItem]];
            [self.navigationItem setAccessibilityElementsHidden:TRUE];```` and this did not affect anything. Likewise with ````self.navigationController.navigationBar````

Comment: what :O ... i tried and it worked for me. I had a navigation controller embeded to my view controller.

Comment: can you post the screenshot of the view hierrachy in your storyboard for your view controller?

Comment: I don't use a storyboard this is entirely programmatic. I am also using iOS 8.4