# How do I disconnect the Navigation Bar from VoiceOver?

Tags: voiceover, uiaccessibility

**Scenario:** I want to be able to disconnect the NavigationBar from Accessibility; or at least be able to control when voice-over reads it.

Here's the code to either change the back-button's label or shut it off. 
However it doesn't have any effect.

```
import UIKit

class ThirdViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = "Third ViewController"
        handleAccessibiltiy()
    }
    
    func handleAccessibiltiy() {
        let navigationItem = self.navigationController?.navigationItem
        let backButton = navigationItem?.backBarButtonItem
        backButton?.accessibilityLabel = "Turkey"
        backButton?.title = "Turkey"
        backButton?.isAccessibilityElement = false
        
    }

}
```

Here's the navigation bar via simulator:

[image]

**Question:** how do I change the navigation item's VoiceOver property to have an effect?

My code doesn't have any affect.

Comment: You may find answers here ⟹ https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/en/mobile/ios/development/#navigation-bar 

Comment: This is a nice overall cursory intro; but doesn't address my specific concern: that I can't alter the Navigator's accessibility.

Comment: I may be wrong but the goal of the different tabs of this specific section is to customize the navigation bar for VoiceOver so that should do the rick, shouldn't it?  

Comment: My original problem was not being able to quiet the VoiceOver of the navigator's back button when I try to return from a popover.  I wanted to change the accessibility focus but the 'back' button always announced itself.

Answer (score 3):

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.accessibilityElementsHidden = true
```

Answer (score 0):

My original problem was shutting off the Accessibility's access to the navigation bar, so upon return from a popup, I can focus on my desired Accessibility target without the 'back button' always being announced.

I believe this is the answer:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.accessibilityElementsHidden=YES;
```

Here's the [Stack Overflow source.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32256952/uibarbuttonitem-how-to-disable-accessibility-ios)